# Some confusions setting up Asterisk IVR menu

Tags: linux, asterisk

I have some confusions regarding setting up Asterisk and your help will be much appreciated!, I have a 4 port FXO card and I have 4 analog lines, currently I have 1 line in the card where a user can call, upon calling he hears a sample ivr menu, my questions are:

1. If i put all 4 lines, how do I make it so I can use all 4 lines on IVR menu, lets say I have given everyone (Number 1)  and 3 people call at a time, the line 1 will go busy for the other 2 users then, how do i resolve it to use all the 4 lines?
2. Is it possible to entertain more than 4 people at a time for just the IVR menu NOT the customer support

Your help will be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you can setup different context for every new line. You can write any number of contextes and put in dialplan almost anything you can imagine, it just matter of skills.

2) PSTN line have 1 wire. So 4 lines is 4 wires. It is analog connection. You can't use same wire for 2 or more channels. IF you need more then 1 per wire, you have use PRI lines.

Comment: Can you answer (1) in detail how to use all 4 lines at once for the IVR menu? like if number 4 is busy, go to number 3, if number 3 is busy go to number 2 like this..

Comment: No, you can't. It is analog lines. Follower can be availible ONLY if other side(PSTN company) support that.